# Display calendar of the user who logs into my website usign REST API of google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am new to Google Calendar and i have been successful in incorporating the Google Calendar on my website, but now what i require is to show the calendar that has been logged in according to the user of the website. Is there a specific method to it?

I do not require the code i just need a direction to start with

TIA

Comment: Your going to have to request access of each user on your website and then link their google account with their user account on your site

Comment: @DaImTo so you are specifying that i need to ask for the authorization from each user who logs in my website like the sample asks for my authorization?

Comment: If you want to access a users google calendar account your going to need their consent.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, i agree. What i meant was to create a page which ask for authorization from the user like given on this page ?
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

Comment: yup you have the right idea.  Then when you get a refresh token back save the refresh token along with your user then you wont need to request access again.

Comment: @DaImTo great just a small question, there is a speculation given of authorization to revoked, how do i check that